# Azure policy to deny adding a second diagnostic setting to any resource if the first diagnostic setting already exists

Tags: azure, azure-policy, azure-diagnostics

Azure policy to deny adding a second diagnostic setting to any resource if the first diagnostic setting already exists

I tried the below code, but it doesn't seem to have any resource details and it doesn't work

```
{
    "mode": "All",
    "policyRule": {
        "if": {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings"
        },
        "then": {
            "effect": "deny"
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Azure policy to deny adding a second diagnostic setting to any resource if the first diagnostic setting already exists: -

The Azure policy is as follows: I found out how avoid the addition of two or more diagnostic settings. If at least one diagnostic parameter is already enabled and set to "true," the policy allows it.

If a resource has several diagnostic settings with enabled set to "true," the policy forbids.

```bash
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings"
        },
        {
          "count": {
            "field": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/logs[*]",
            "where": {
              "allOf": [
                {
                  "field": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings/logs[*].enabled",
                  "equals": "true"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "greater": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

**Created successfully:**

[image]

*Azure Policy* [`COUNT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/pattern-count-operator) *operator.*

Comment: But my ask is different. I want it to not create multiple diagnostics settings (not multiple settings inside the same diagnostic setting)

Comment: Understood, that is why I have checked for the logs field. If logs are enabled, then the policy should deny adding any more logs which is nothing but diagnostic settings. If that is not the scenario, can you elaborate more on your issue. @jarvis93

Comment: let's say I have a diagnostic setting "ds1", sending "Audit Logs" to "xyz" log analytics workspace.
I wouldn't want someone creating another diagnostic setting "ds2", sending "Azure Policy Evaluation Details" logs to "abc"(or anyother) log analytics workspace.

**(the policy you mentioned denys creation of new diagnostic setting with logs filed enabled. But it doesn't check if there is an existing ds1 exists. Irrespective of if there is existing setting, it denys creation)**